# How to add an adapter to a listView?

Tags: android, listview

I have the following code to add a custom adapter to a listView but it gives the following error on the line where I set the adapter:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x68

```
public class PackageListFragment extends Fragment {

    PackageAdapter packageItemAdapter;
    ArrayList<PackageClass> list;
    PackageClass packageList;
    TextView mainLine;
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_aps__main, container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.packageList);
        try{
            list = getAllPackages();
            packageItemAdapter = new PackageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, list);
            lv.setAdapter(packageItemAdapter);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("listItem", ex.toString());
    }
    return rootView;
}

public ArrayList<PackageClass> getAllPackages() throws Exception{
    return new DBFunctions(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).RetrieveAllPackage();
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong? My application stops without even starting :(

Comment: Can you show your `PackageAdapter`? I think you are using something there, maybe on the `getView()` method, that its causing this issue. Make sure you have all the resource strings as you should... you are missing one when decalring string like `R.string.your_string`

Comment: @yugidroid yes you are right, I was doing something hilarious in getView() :P

Answer (score 0):

After editing your question, I notice one of your brackets in the `try`/`catch` block seems wrong. I copied your code into this answer and commented the potentially offending bracket. But this may just be a mistake in the question and not your code, since I don't believe it would compile with this problem.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_aps__main, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.packageList);
    try{
        list = getAllPackages();
        packageItemAdapter = new PackageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, list);
        lv.setAdapter(packageItemAdapter);
    }

} // <---- seems out of place

catch(Exception ex){
    Log.e("listItem", ex.toString());
}

return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Yes it was indeed mistake in the question since I edited the code here and removed an extra if/else . Anyhow I have worked out my problem, it was the getView function in custom adapter class...